# How to show data in database with a JTable

Tags: java, mysql

I am unable to show data in a database with JTable, what is wrong?

MyButton Here;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String sorgu="SELECT arac_marka=? , arac_model=? , arac_yas=? , arac_adet=? , arac_orjinallik=? , arac_renk=? , arac_firma='?' , urunkodu=? FROM calisan_urun_ekle";
        DBConnection.Goster(urunkodu.getText(),arac_marka.getText(), arac_model.getText(), arac_yas.getText(), arac_adet.getText(), arac_orjinal.getText(), arac_renk.getText(), arac_firma.getText(), sorgu);      

        calisan_tablosu.setModel(DBConection);

        }
    }
```

And DBConnection

```
public static void Goster(String arac_marka, String arac_model, String arac_yas, String arac_adet,String arac_orjinal,String arac_renk,String arac_firma,String urunkodu,String sorgu){


connection();

try
{
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username , pass);
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(sorgu);

    statement.setString(1, arac_marka);
    statement.setString(2, arac_model);
    statement.setString(3, arac_yas);
    statement.setString(4, arac_adet);
    statement.setString(5, arac_orjinal);
    statement.setString(6, arac_renk);
    statement.setString(7, arac_firma);
    statement.setString(7, urunkodu);


    statement.executeQuery();
    statement.close();
    connect.close();
```

And MyTable

```
calisan_tablosu = new JTable();
    calisan_tablosu.setBounds(28, 250, 590, 184);
    layeredPane.add(calisan_tablosu);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the problem?

Comment: if i click button show me this problems... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel

Comment: What's DBConnection?

Comment: @MadProgrammer DBConnection.java is my connection class

Comment: Annnnd, what does it look like? How does it work? From my perspective, it doesn't look like an instance variable, but a class with static utility methods

Comment: @MadProgrammer if i use insert delete or update its working. but  i use select and with jtable show me a lot problems. how can i show in jtable :( and what's add in setmodel. Because this code hasnt got while or for and if

Comment: Without a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, it's all guess work

Comment: @MadProgrammer how can i do? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
 try{
        String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db1";
    ResultSet rs=null;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
       String query="select * from customer";
        PreparedStatement pst=null;
        pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
       rs=pst.executeQuery();

        DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel(); 
        tm.setRowCount(0);

        while(rs.next())
        {
           Object o[]={rs.getInt("Column1_name_in_table(ie:-Cid)"),rs.getString("Cname"),rs.getString("Ccity")}; 
           tm.addRow(o);
        }

   }
    catch(SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage()); 
    }
```